# Track onclick video in mix-panel using javascript mix-panel API

Tags: javascript, html, css, mixpanel

I have embed video in my site. video is playing on click i want to track events of video using mixpanel
**Here is my html code**

```
<section class="third-section">
  <div style="width:100%">
    <div class="flex-video widescreen" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;">
      <video id="mid_section_video" class="all_videos" preload="auto"  muted=”muted” poster="{% static 'images/wikireviews.jpg' %}">
        {% trans "Your browser does not support the video tag." %}
      </video>                                  
    </div>
  </div>                            
  <div class="vidoe-tag">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="video-btn"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

When click on video i want track this event using mixpanel i have refer Mixpanel javascript API for this, i have include Mixpanel code into my site but its not working.  I want to capture event on `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="video-btn"></a>` this

**Js code is which embed the video**

```
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {     
        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.src = src;
        source.type = type;
        element.appendChild(source);
    }
        var video;
        video = document.getElementById('mid_section_video');
        addSourceToVideo(video, STATIC_PATH+"videos/webm/video_011.webm", "video/webm");
        addSourceToVideo(video, STATIC_PATH+"videos/webm/video_011.ogg", "video/ogg");
        addSourceToVideo(video, STATIC_PATH+"videos/mp4/video_011.mp4", "video/mp4");
```

**Mixpanel code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  mixpanel.track("Video play");
</script>
```

How to track video on cilck